Recommend deletion for low quality posts
When reviewing the "Low quality posts" queue, one issue that I commonly find there is that some posts fail to provide useful insights on the question. They might be technically correct, or at least not strictly wrong, yet they bring little value. 
Most of the times, the way I deal with these low quality posts is to "Recommend deletion", unless they are the poster's first post, in which case I might choose to comment. 
And on a side note, I must say that (especially) Chinese people do that very often. They are nice and all and answer your question in an extremely exact way:

Q: "Can I use the term XYZ to express ABC?" 
  A: "Sure!"

whereas I think it's obvious, especially in the context of a Q&A website like this one, that the more value you provide with your answer, the more you are fulfilling the very purpose of being here.
One example that I have recently commented on is this. 

However, back to the point, I click the button, then I'm asked to provide a motivation, but there's none consistent with my reasoning. So I just click "No comment needed".
Am I doing it right? Is it correct to delete a low-value post? Is it correct to choose "No comment needed"? Is there an official stance of the moderators/community about low-value low-quality posts? 
Thank you
